# Scala: Source.fromInputStream failed for bigger input

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, inputstream

I am reading data from AWS S3. The following code works fine if the input file is small. It failed when the input file is big. Is there any parameter I can modify to increase the buffer size or anything so it can handle bigger input file as well? Thanks!

```
    val s3Object= s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("myBucket", "myPath/myFile.csv"));

    val myData = Source.fromInputStream(s3Object.getObjectContent()).getLines()
    for (line <- myData) {
        val data = line.split(",")
        myMap.put(data(0), data(1).toDouble)
    }

    println(" my map : " + myMap.toString())
```

Comment: What exactly is the failure that you are getting when the input is big?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/io/Source.scala#L153) you can see that internally it calls `Source.createBufferedSource`.  You can use that to create your own version with a bigger buffer size.

These are the lines of code from scala:

```
  def createBufferedSource(
    inputStream: InputStream,
    bufferSize: Int = DefaultBufSize,
    reset: () => Source = null,
    close: () => Unit = null
  )(implicit codec: Codec): BufferedSource = {
    // workaround for default arguments being unable to refer to other parameters
    val resetFn = if (reset == null) () => createBufferedSource(inputStream, bufferSize, reset, close)(codec) else reset

    new BufferedSource(inputStream, bufferSize)(codec) withReset resetFn withClose close
  }

  def fromInputStream(is: InputStream, enc: String): BufferedSource =
    fromInputStream(is)(Codec(enc))

  def fromInputStream(is: InputStream)(implicit codec: Codec): BufferedSource =
    createBufferedSource(is, reset = () => fromInputStream(is)(codec), close = () => is.close())(codec)
```

Edit: Now that I have thought about your issue a bit more, you can increase the buffer size in this way, but I'm not sure that this will actually fix your issue